# How to do multi-tiered application deployment using Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, nginx, docker-swarm

I want to use following deployment architecture.

- One machine running my webserver(nginx)
- Two or more machines running uwsgi
- Postgresql as my db on another server.

All the three are three different host machines on AWS. During development I used docker and was able to run all these three on my local machine. But I am clueless now as I want to split those three into three separate hosts and run it. Any guidance, clues, references will be greatly appreciated. I preferably want to do this using docker.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really adamant on keeping the services separate on individual hosts then there's nothing stopping you from still using your containers on a Docker installed EC2 host for nginx/uswgi, you could even use a CoreOS AMI which comes with a nice secure Docker instance pre-loaded (https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-on-ec2.html).

For the database use PostgreSQL on AWS RDS.

If you're running containers you can also look at AWS ECS which is Amazons container service, which would be my initial recommendation, but I saw that you wanted all these services to be on individual hosts.

Comment: Yes, I want them to be on individual hosts but I am unable to find any tutorial or guide as to how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use docker stack to deploy the application in swarm,
join the other 2 hosts as worker and use the below option 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#placement
`deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager`

change the node role as manager or worker1 or workern this will restrict the services to run on individual hosts.
you can also make this more secure by using vpn if you wish

Comment: You mean I can have webserver as one host and as manager and uwsgi and db as other worker hosts? Correct me if I am wrong, which I feel I am.

Comment: To summarize, I will need to create swarm on my webserver host, then get uwsgi and db host to join this swarm as workers. Now they will be in same network and should work. Do I need to specify anywhere what my IPs are for other hosts?

Comment: you can also try this https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/#deployment-options this will help you create a swarm in aws with cloudwatch for logs

Comment: "you can also try this". Were you pointing to something? Oh the link came in later.

Comment: sorry for pressing ENTER when i was typing
,you can also do this manually as you had mentioned in previous comment

Comment: One more question, where to I put my application code? I mean its easy on standalone machine but if I have to set it up like this. Where do I put my application that also hosts my compose file.

Comment: deploy the application in manager, the manager will distribute according to the docker compose yml file